# Restore linux partition from remote server

Tags: linux, restore, netcat

I have a running server with /dev/sda1 partition and a remote server with /dev/sda1 partion also.
I want to clone the partition of running server to remote server.

I want to try this:

On remote server:

```
nc -l -p 2000 | bzip2 -d | dd of=/dev/sda1
```

On running server:

```
bzip2 -c /dev/sda1 | nc 192.168.1.10 2000
```

It's the right way or there are some others better solutions?

Comment: Make sure it is umounted before reading from the block device.

Comment: You mean the running server partition? What happens if isn't unmounted?

Comment: You don't get a clean copy because the running system can write to it after you've attempted to copy the partition.

Comment: I doubt it's the right way, but before getting into details, please let us know if sda1 hold a mounted filesystem and, if yes, which one (mount point, filesystem type and brief description of contained data). Also, It would be useful to know what is "exactly" your problem. I mean: the problem you're trying to solve with such a low-level copy (a backup? A D/R Plan? A simple "exercise"? A network test? A migration?)

Comment: The running server filesystem is ext3 type with RAID 10 mode and is a running server with debian operating system. It is a monitoring server and the remote server was identical. After a disk corruption we need to restore the same data into remote server with the identical configuration of running server.